# Does provideClientHydration fully replace TransferStateAPI and TransferHttpCacheModule?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Since Angular 16 there is a new `provideClientHydration` function for SSR hydration:

```
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
    ...
  ],
};
```

However, I can not discern if this is supposed to **fully** replace the previous solutions like creating two interceptors (one for transferring browser state and one for server state) and importing `TransferHttpCacheModule`.

I stumbled on [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@pratheeshrussell/an-introduction-to-angular-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-nestjs-c121185d5824) which seems to suggest that it does replace those solutions, but I haven't found an official source to confirm this.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does !

`provideClientHydration()` will call `withHttpTransferCache()` if `NoHttpTransferCache` isn't specified.

Since `withHttpTransferCache` isn't public here is the current implementation :

It does set the providers for the cache like the `TransferHttpCacheModule` and you can also see that the interceptor will return the cached values until the app is stable !

```
export function withHttpTransferCache(): Provider[] {
  return [
    {
      provide: CACHE_STATE,
      useFactory: () => {
        inject(ENABLED_SSR_FEATURES).add('httpcache');
        return {isCacheActive: true};
      }
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_ROOT_INTERCEPTOR_FNS,
      useValue: transferCacheInterceptorFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [TransferState, CACHE_STATE]
    },
    {
      provide: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER,
      multi: true,
      useFactory: () => {
        const appRef = inject(ApplicationRef);
        const cacheState = inject(CACHE_STATE);

        return () => {
          appRef.isStable.pipe(first((isStable) => isStable)).toPromise().then(() => {
            cacheState.isCacheActive = false;
          });
        };
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/440684ddb4a2b651e4fbd301978b7895f1750c1b/packages/common/http/src/transfer_cache.ts#L147-L177