# angular universal 17 prerender dynamic content

Tags: angular, angular-universal, static-site-generation

With Angular 17 prerendering is available, what I haven't been able to determine from the Angular docs is how to use dynamic content from an external API to drive the prerendered routes.

Routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        title: 'Home page'
      },
      {
        path: 'article/:id',
        component: ArticleDetailsComponent,
        title: 'Article Details'
      }
];
```

I have a mock data service and these routes are prerendered. However I can't figure out how to call my REST API for my CMS at build time.  The CMS is called fine at run time but that content isn't available during build time.  My mock homepage links to 3 articles, `/article/1`, `/article/2`, and `/article/3`

`article.service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  articleList: Article[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'my article time',
      subTitle: 'sub title'
    }
...
  ]

  getArticleById(id: number): Article | undefined {
    let article = this.articleList.find(article => article.id === id);

    //ideally long term this is done upstream by a performant go app
    if (article !== undefined) {
      article = this.transformContent(article);
    }

    return article;
  }


  getArticleFromCMS(): Observable<Content> {
    return this.http.get<Content>('https://example.com')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Content>('getArticle', {}))
      );
  }
```

`article-details.component.ts`

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleService } from '../article.service';
import { Article, CMSContent } from '../article';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-details',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './article-details.component.html',
  styleUrl: './article-details.component.css'
})
export class ArticleDetailsComponent {
  route: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  articleService = inject(ArticleService);
  article: Article | undefined;
  cmsContent: CMSContent | undefined;

  constructor() {
    const articleID = Number(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    this.article = this.articleService.getArticleById(articleID);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getArticles();
  }

  getArticles(): void {
    this.articleService.getArticleFromCMS()
      .subscribe(article => this.cmsContent = article.content[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read the tag info of the tags you add to make sure they make sense for your question. For instance, [tag:angularjs] states, "Use for questions about AngularJS (1.x), the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag." And you are using it for Angular 17.

Comment: You need to use [`provideClientHydration`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76990810/8941307)

Answer (score 0):

I refered the documentation for [`Prerendering parameterized routes`](https://angular.io/guide/prerendering#prerendering-parameterized-routes)

I created a file `routes.txt`

```
/article/1
/article/2
/article/3
```

Then I added the file, to the angular.json like so

```
…
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "prerender": {
          "routesFile": "routes.txt"
        },
      },
…
```

When I ran `ng build`, I saw the folders getting created for the routes specified in `routes.txt`

Please find below working example from stackblitz, with a `dist` folder containing the pre rendered routes!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zm4aem?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=prerender%2Fangular.json,prerender%2Froutes.txt,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.routes.ts,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmock.service.ts,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.config.ts,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.scss,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Farticle-details%2Farticle-details.component.ts,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Farticle-details%2Farticle-details.component.scss,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Farticle-details%2Farticle-details.component.html,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,prerender%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.spec.ts&title=node.new%20Starter)

Comment: maybe I could of done better of clarifying in the question but those routes of /article/1, /article/2, /article/2 are being pre-rendered with static json in the article.service however dynamic content pulled in via the http client is not being used in the pre-render process

Comment: @JeffSloyer Am not sure how my output is lacking, I am getting the data from an API call and the content is populated on the UI as expected as static pages when I check the dist folder, if you have some advanced angular logic happening, it needs to happen on the client only, but for a basic CMS, this solution should work fine!

Comment: @JeffSloyer the purpose of prerendering is to just make the content of the website indexable by search engines, it does not offer full fledged angular to static page conversion