# Angular SSR - Load Data From Server Only

Tags: angular, hydration, angular-ssr

I'm trying to load data from the server only in Angular SSR (Universal). I have one idea from [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53168).

##### data-service.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class DataServiceService {
  abstract get(id: string): string
}

export class DataServiceServiceServer extends DataServiceService {
   get(id: string): string {
    return 'server-data-performed-with-secret-tokens';
   }
}

export class DataServiceServiceBrowser extends DataServiceService {
  get(id: string): string {
   return 'browser-data';
  }
}
```

##### app.config.server.ts

```
const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    {
      provide: DataServiceService,
      useClass: DataServiceServiceServer
    }
  ]
};
```

##### app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    {
      provide: DataServiceService,
      useClass: DataServiceServiceBrowser,
    },
  ],
};
```

This will make sure the class can be used in both the server and the browser.

However, this returns different data on the client than the server. I'm thinking I would use the [TransferState classes](https://github.com/jdgamble555/angular-state-test/blob/master/src/app/state.service.ts).

However, it looks like [you don't need transferState with provideClientHydration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990810/does-provideclienthydration-fully-replace-transferstateapi-and-transferhttpcache).

When I try adding the `transferState` to this, it will not load on the client. Do I even need `transferState`, or is there a better way?

### Repo

- [GitHub](https://github.com/jdgamble555/angular-state-test/tree/master)

[image: Open in StackBlitz]

How can I use this to hydrate the client with the server value?

Comment: Got it working - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/preloading-data-in-angular-universal-20lj